# Lambda function concurrent invocation per event trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is is logging into a server on a specific interval, defined from a CloudWatch event rule. There are multiple servers that need to be logged into on different intervals, each defined by their own respective CloudWatch event rule. However, I only want one lambda function invocation hitting a specific server at a time. Can each CloudWatch event rule be limited to just one lambda function invocation at a time, or would I have to create a duplicate lambda function for each specific CloudWatch event rule and set the concurrent invocation to 1 that way? I was hoping to avoid that as it just adds duplicate lambda functions. I'd just want to keep it simple, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IDs of these instances, you can pass them as arguments to your CloudWatch Event rules in the form of **constant**:

[image]

Your **single function** would get the ID of the instance from the `event` object and perform operations on that one specific instance.

Comment: I understand that, but on each event trigger, would only one lambda function be invoked at a time?

Comment: @Jasonca1 Yes, I think this is what you are asking for?

Comment: yes that is what I am asking for. Now if I wanted to have a separate lambda function that runs on a CloudWatch event rule, and every cloud watch event trigger would spin up 5 invocations (with each invocation being passed in the same Constant JSON test input) would that be possible as well?